# In the derivation of canonical distribution why does one linearize entropy (and not something else?)

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I know that there are (at least) two ways to derive the canonical distribution.

I am interested in the one where one considers the entropy of the reservoir (with which the system we are considering is in thermal equilibrium) as a function of the energy of the system.

One wants to use the entropy to count the possible configurations of the reservoir that correspond to a given state of the system - and up to here I agree of course.

The step which I cannot understand is the one where one linearizes the entropy as a function of the energy of the large system (around the equilibrum energy). From this linearization the canonical distribution follows immediately, taking into account that the number of configurations is an exponential function of the entropy.

I agree that it is possible to linearize the entropy, as the energy that is exchanged between system and reservoir is small with respect to the energy of the - large - reservoir. My concern is - if I linearize a different function of the number of configurations, I get a different distribution ... for example why can't I linearize the the square root of the logarithm of the number of configurations? Then I would get a different distribution. A wrong distribution, but that is the point ... how do I know beforehand what to linearize?

(I try adding a few equations as suggested in the comments)

Let us define -for example- the following function of the number of configurations of the reservoir

$f = {\left[ {\log \left( {{N_{\text{config}}}} \right)} \right]^2}$

I then say that this function will be linear in the energy of the reservoir (around the average energy $E_0$)

$f \approx {f_0} + \delta \left( {E - {E_0}} \right)$

Then I get

${N_{\text{config}}} = \exp \left( {\sqrt f } \right) \approx \exp \left( {\sqrt {{f_0} + \delta \left( {E - {E_0}} \right)} } \right)$

From which I get a probability distribution which is not *right*. I could obviously expand the square root in Taylor series ... but why should I???
When figuring out the example I got somehow the sensation that the distribution that comes out of my example is not "universal" enough to be the right one; something like: we should look for the distribution that does not change with the size of the reservoir - and therefore with $E_0$ - as long as the reservoir is large enough. That will tell us what is the right function of $N_{config}$ that we need to expand in Taylor series. But I haven't yet put down this idea in precise terms.

Comment: It might be useful to include an equation or two of your derivation to show what it is you mean in math & words.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the derivation you are talking about?

Comment: A reference is for example Landau, Statistical Physics - and I think I saw the same derivation in Callen, Thermodynamics. I am adding the equation right now.